# Redirect Github pages Jekyll site into sub-directory

Tags: redirect, jekyll, github-pages

I'm trying to build a website using Jekyll on Github pages to replace my old one which was hosted at www.wyversolutions.co.uk/cms

I want to ensure that when someone goes to www.wyversolutions.co.uk it automatically pushes them to www.wyversolutions.co.uk/cms

I have already set {{ site.baseurl }} to /cms so all the pages and links render properly there.

But how can I do the redirect on the root level? In Apache this would be done use a 301 redirect, but I can't find an equivalent that will work with Jekyll.

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [jekyll/jekyll-redirect-from plugin](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-redirect-from) that works on github pages.